# Searching for a piece of code to update a textarea by selecting an <option> inside a <select>

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, jquery-events

Here is the code I've written a few days ago. I'm relatively new to this PHP scene and not quite sure how I can make this work. I want that the user can select their file to appear inside the textarea. For that I created a `<select>` where they can obviously select the file like said already. Are any cool helpers out there, that can send me a tip or even the whole answer and code for this?

```
<div class="bg-3 row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                    <div class="build_output">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">

                      <form action="viewer.php" method="post">
                        <div class="bg-3-content">
                          <div class="bg-3-hline">
                            <h2>Inhalt von <?php echo $selected; ?></h2>
                          </div>
                          <div class="bg-3-text">
                            <p>Hier sehen sie den Inhalt der Datei <?php echo $selected; ?> aus dem Ordner <?php echo $ordner; ?>. <br> Sie können diesen Text bearbeiten und mit einem Klick auf "Speichern" die Ursprungsdatei mit dem neuen Text überschreiben.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>


                        <select name="dateien">
                          <?php
                          $ordner = "files";
                          $alledateien = scandir($ordner);
                          foreach ($alledateien as $datei) {
                            $dateiinfo = pathinfo($ordner."/".$datei);
                              $size = ceil(filesize($ordner."/".$datei)/1024);
                               if ($datei != "." && $datei != ".."  && $datei != "_notes") {
                               $bildtypen = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
                               if(in_array($dateiinfo['extension'], $bildtypen))
                               { ?>
                              <?php
                               }else{
                                  ?>
                                <option><?php echo $dateiinfo['filename']; ?> (<?php echo $dateiinfo['extension']; ?> | <?php echo $size ; ?>kb)</option>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php
                                 };
                             };
                             ?>
                           </select>

                        <?php
                          $selected = $_POST['dateien'];
                        ?>

                        <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="output" cols="60" rows="20">
                            <?php

                              $output = file_get_contents($dateiinfo['dirname']."/".$selected);

                              echo $output;

                              $latestContent = $_POST['output'];

                            ?>
                        </textarea>

                        <br>

                      <input class="output-save" type="submit" value="Speichern" />
                      <a href="#" class="output-abort">Abbrechen</a>

                      </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
              </div> <!--bg-3--->
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you need the text area to change when a user selects an option, you therefore need JavaScript to achieve this. You should tag this question as JavaScript so people who are watching the JavaScript tag can help.

Comment: Thanks for the introduction, but your question lacks an actual question. Please describe in more detail what this code should do, what it currently does (including any error messages), what you're stuck with and what you've tried yourself to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but there are literally no error messages. The code is supposed to bring up all files, that are in the folder files, in the section. Then the user can select one and the text inside this file is going to be shown in the textarea. The problem now is, that the textarea doesn't update wehen user select one file...

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery you can do all kinds of manipulations to your HTML.

#### jQuery

```
// If your select dropdown changes
$(document).on('change', '.selector', function () {
    // Get the selected option
    var option = $(this).val();
    // If the option is optionone
    if (option == 'optionone') {
        // Change a textarea value
        $('.textarea-selector').html('something');
    }
});
```

#### HTML

```
<select class="selector">
    <option value="optionone">Option one</option>
    <option value="optiontwo">Option two</option>
</select>

<textarea class="textarea-selector">this will change</textarea>
```

I know this is a very simple example but it will illustrate a good way to solve your problem nontheless.

Comment: Thank you, but i see no way to bring up the file (,that the user took) with jQuery. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("change", ":file", function() {
  file = $(this).prop('files')[0];
  $("#inpFileName").val(file.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="input-group-btn">Browse&hellip;
<input style="display: none;" type="file"> </label> 
<input class="form-control" disabled id="inpFileName" type="text">
```

You can handle input changes to the file input field by using the `change`-Event.